# Realizar app web con angular y java

Tags: java, angularjs, web

Buenos amigos esa es mi duda, es posible realizar una aplicacion web usando backend de java? He leido que usan angular con php y/o webservices, mas sin embargo no he visto mucha info sobre java, es posible traer datos a la vista usando clases java? Espero sus comentarios y/o sugerencias

Comment: La respuesta es __SI__. Pero esta publicación, en su estado actual, no cumple con las políticas de calidad de la comunidad. Por favor consulta esta guía _"[ask]"_ y considera editarla para que se ajuste al estándar. Dado que [es.so] no acepta preguntas donde se solicitan comentarios, sugerencias, opiniones o ideas, procedo a votar para el cierre.

Answer (score 3):

Sí se puede. Lo que importa de lado de Java es generar los microservicios. Existen algunos frameworks que pueden ayudarte con esto:

- [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), el cual es una oferta de pivotal y basado en el framework Spring.
- [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.0/docs/), que también permite la creación e integración de microservicios.
- [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io), que provee la base para generar una aplicación Web en Angular (versiones 1, 2 y 4) y backend con SpringBoot.
- Usar un ESB como [mule](/questions/tagged/mule) o Fuse. Esta opción puede ser un poco más pesada pero también es una alternativa si requieres usar más funcionalidades de lado de backend como por ejemplo procesamiento de archivos, sftp, colas, etc.
- También se puede realizar usando JAX-RS y un servidor de aplicaciones ligero/parcial que están customizados para proveer solo lo necesario como lo sería [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly.org/news/2015/05/05/WildFly-Swarm-Released/).
- Una opción muy interesante también es la de [Amazon Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/es/lambda/?nc1=h_ls) y su propuesta de computación sin servidor (conocido como [serverless computing](https://aws.amazon.com/es/serverless/?nc1=h_ls)). Te recomendaría revisar su [documentación para Java](https://aws.amazon.com/es/sdk-for-java/). Tiene su SDK particular y sus lineamientos, así que es muy probable que sea muy distinto a las opciones mencionadas previamente.

Comment: *"Lo que importa de lado de Java es generar los microservicios"* -> No son microservicios, si bien SpringBoot si puede generar microservicios, no son necesarios para generar una api REST, que es lo que necesitas para enlazar con Angular.